# Biblatex lncs formatting only

Tags: biblatex, lncs

I need to use lncs format for my bibliography for a document class of `book`

When using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}


\usepackage[
doi=false
,isbn=false
,url=false
,backend=biber
,style=lncs
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkbibparens{\mkpageprefix[pagination]    [\mknormrange]{#1}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}%
\bibopenbracket}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\bibopenbracket}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}
{\bibclosebracket
\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{./msc_cs.bib}   

\begin{document}    
\nocite{Steyn2017,Paar2011,Jensen1980,Jonesb} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is given by

[image]

The indentation of the second line does not match the indentation of the authors surname. There is also an extra `.` before item 3, and if `Jonesb` is not referenced the extra `.` is not here any more.

```
@Article{Jonesb,
  author        = {Jones, Cliff B.},
  title         = {SYSTEMATIC SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT USING VDM SECOND EDITION},
}

@Article{Jensen1980,
  author          = {Kurt Jensen},
  title           = {{Coloured Petri Nets}},
  year            = {1980},
  pages           = {248--299},
  doi             = {10.1007/978-3-540-47919-2_10},
  booktitle       = {Petri Nets: Central Models and Their Properties},
  publisher       = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
}

@InProceedings{Steyn2017,
  author    = {Theunis J. Steyn and Stefan Gruner},
  title     = {A new optional parallelism operator in {CSP} for wireless sensor networks},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the South African Institute of Computer Scientists and Information Technologists on - {SAICSIT} {\textquotesingle}17},
  year      = {2017},
  publisher = {{ACM} Press},
  doi       = {10.1145/3129416.3129431},
}

@InProceedings{Paar2011,
  author    = {Alexander Paar and Stefan Gruner},
  title     = {Static typing with value space-based subtyping},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the South African Institute of Computer Scientists and Information Technologists Conference on Knowledge, Innovation and Leadership in a Diverse, Multidisciplinary Environment - {SAICSIT} {\textquotesingle}11},
  year      = {2011},
  publisher = {{ACM} Press},
  doi       = {10.1145/2072221.2072242},
}
```

Comment: There is https://github.com/gvdgdo/biblatex-lncs

Comment: For a long bibliography entry the line wraps and the indentation of the second line is not the same as the authors surname

Comment: If you have specific issues with that style I suggest you add an example document to your question that reproduces the undesired behaviour. I don't know the LNCS guidelines and so you have to be specific and explain what behaviour you would like to see.

Comment: Looks like `biblatex-lncs` doesn't cope particularly well with missing information. The symptom is quite weird, I don't have time to investigate it properly, but `Jonesb` is definitely missing required fields and it probably should not SHOUT. Re the weird indentation: At the moment my guess is that the indentation is correct and that some part of the code introduces an unwanted spurious space. If we can find it, the first line will start just a tad farther to the left and things should align.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `biblatex-lncs` style leaves a lot to be desired. There are many problems with its internal implementation and I would be inclined to abandon it and start with one of the existing standard styles.

Having said that, we can work around the particular problems you ask about in your question.

The spacing issue is caused by a bug in `\DeclareNameFormat{author}` and `\DeclareNameFormat{editor}` in `lncs.bbx`. These two macros use the `\ifblank` test, but should use the `\ifdefvoid` test. The test gives the wrong result and an extra space is inserted.

The weird period at the start of entry number 3 is caused by punctuation left in the punctuation buffer when no other field is inserted after the `title`. As @moewe points out in the comments, you should fix this entry to include the right fields (and be the right type—it should be a `book`). But there is also a bug in the `finentry` macro in `lncs.bbx`. Final punctuation (`\finentrypunct`) should be inserted by this macro, but it isn't. We can fix this by redefining `\finentrypunct` and redefining the `finentry` macro.

`Jensen1980` is also wrong because you have it as the wrong type. It should be `inbook`. Except `biblatex-lncs` does not support the `inbook` entry type. Aliasing `inproceedings` to `inbook` *might* give an approximation to the required output, but I don't really know.

But really these are just workarounds for a broken style. I wouldn't use it.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Jonesb,
  author = {Jones, Cliff B.},
  title = {Systematic Software Development Using {VDM} (2nd ed.)},
  year = {1990},
  publisher = {Prentice-Hall},
  address = {Upper Saddle River, NJ},
}

@Article{Jensen1980,
  author          = {Kurt Jensen},
  title           = {{Coloured Petri Nets}},
  year            = {1980},
  pages           = {248--299},
  doi             = {10.1007/978-3-540-47919-2_10},
  booktitle       = {Petri Nets: Central Models and Their Properties},
  publisher       = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
}

@InProceedings{Steyn2017,
  author    = {Theunis J. Steyn and Stefan Gruner},
  title     = {A new optional parallelism operator in {CSP} for wireless sensor networks},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the South African Institute of Computer Scientists and Information Technologists on - {SAICSIT} {\textquotesingle}17},
  year      = {2017},
  publisher = {{ACM} Press},
  doi       = {10.1145/3129416.3129431},
}

@InProceedings{Paar2011,
  author    = {Alexander Paar and Stefan Gruner},
  title     = {Static typing with value space-based subtyping},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the South African Institute of Computer Scientists and Information Technologists Conference on Knowledge, Innovation and Leadership in a Diverse, Multidisciplinary Environment - {SAICSIT} {\textquotesingle}11},
  year      = {2011},
  publisher = {{ACM} Press},
  doi       = {10.1145/2072221.2072242},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
doi=false
,isbn=false
,url=false
,backend=biber
,style=lncs
]{biblatex}

% FIXES FOR BROKEN lncs.bbx
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\space}\namepartfamily, \namepartgiveni%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}%
    {}%
}
\DeclareNameFormat{editor}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\space}\namepartfamily, \namepartgiveni%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}%
    {\space\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>1}
      {(\bibstring{editors})}
      {(\bibstring{editor})}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\settoggle{lncs:lncs}{false}\finentry}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{inbook}{inproceedings}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1}
% END FIXES FOR BROKEN lncs.bbx

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkbibparens{\mkpageprefix[pagination]    [\mknormrange]{#1}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}%
\bibopenbracket}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\bibopenbracket}
    {}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}
{\bibclosebracket
\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}   

\begin{document}    
\nocite{Steyn2017,Paar2011,Jensen1980,Jonesb} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: did decide not to use the package

Answer (score 3):

There is a fork https://github.com/NorwegianRockCat/biblatex-lncs that seems to fix many of these problems. Still, the `misc` entry type was missing. I've added it in [my fork](https://github.com/ponder-lab/biblatex-lncs).

Comment: Don't forget to propose your change upstream so that it can be incorporated!

Comment: @FrederickNord https://github.com/NorwegianRockCat/biblatex-lncs/pull/1